# How to make onesignal push-notification alert in app foreground

Tags: java, android, push-notification, onesignal

I want my OneSignal push-notification to alert in foreground. I want notification to alert when the app is not running in phone's background.
 I already have my background alert working.

```
OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();
```

I expect the app to notify phones even when the app is not running in background. (That s foreground notification )

Answer (score 1):

Create a class named application class

```
public class ApplicationClass extends MultiDexApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true).setNotificationOpenedHandler(new NotificationOpenHandler(this))
                .init();




    }
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(context);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

and add this class to manifest like below

```
<application
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_icon_updated"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But i'm getting error "Cant resolve symbol 'MultiDexApplicaton'."

Comment: add multiDexEnabled true in android{} in app level gradle